# Need a hint on what's wrong - polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I'm asked to solve the following

$$ \int^2_0 \int^\sqrt{4-y²}_0 \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} dxdy $$

I thought about using polar coordinates:

(1) $0 \le x \le \sqrt{4-y^2}$ is the upper half of a circumference with radius 2 and centered on the origin.

(2) $ 0 \le y \le 2 $ is the region between y=0 and y=2, which contains (1)

So

$-2 \le r \le 2$ because of (1)

$0 \le \theta \le \pi$  because of (1)

And since $dxdy \rightarrow rdrd\theta$ and $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

$$\int^\pi_0 \int^2_{-2} \sqrt{4-r^2} r drd\theta$$

But $ \int^2_{-2} \sqrt{4-r^2} r dr = 0$ (using $u=4-r^2, du=-2r$ for the indefinite) so the whole thing is zero.

Which seems wrong - shouldn't the result be the area of the region limited by (1) and (2)? I then input the original integral on Wolfram|Alpha to check and [it did not return zero](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28+integrate+sqrt%284-x%C2%B2-y%C2%B2%29+dx+from+0+to+sqrt%284-y%C2%B2%29+%29+dy+from+0+to+2). Any hints on what I'm doing wrong or what I should do?

Comment: I think it should be $0\leq r\leq 2$ instead of $-2\leq r\leq 2$.

Comment: @Paul is correct. $r$ is the radial distance in polar plane. It ranges from 0 to whatever bound you have.

Comment: Of course, silly mistake. Thanks Paul for pointing out and Torsten for elaborating.

Comment: Another mistake: $0\leq \theta\leq\pi/2,$ see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your intergral as double integral $$\iint_X\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}dxdy$$ and draw the picture of $X.$ Then you will get
$$
X=\{(x,y)\mid x\geq 0,\ y\geq 0, x^2+y^2\leq 4\}=\{(r,\theta)\mid 0\leq r\leq 2,\ 0\leq\theta\leq\pi/2\}
$$

Comment: Note: double integral would look better if you use `\iint`: $\iint$

Comment: @Ruslan: thanks, corrected.